# external hard drive showing up in device manager but not in windows explorer

Tags: external-hard-drive

my external hard drive has been dropped from a metere hight and when i connect to laptop It is recognized as a device and showing up in device manager but not appearing  in windows explorer.  In disk manager its showing as Disk 1 and initialize , i tried to initialize but its not working, when i connect hard disk is getting power and blue/ white light on its spinning and stopping after a minute, when i click on eject device its taking command and safely remove hardware happening and bluw color light blinking and power is off., what could be the problem for not appearing my hard drive in explorer and why its not getting initiated?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms seem very much similar to that of my external hard disk.

The possible reason is your harddisk's meta information might have been corrupted. So it is getting detected as a drive but windows could not find the entry point to access the device.

You might try disk repair softwares to repair your disk. But I am not sure that will help you. I have lost 2 of my hard disks because of similar reasons.

My suggestion is not to invest time repairing the same unless you have very important data which you cannot get any further.

If you want to recollect the data, I recommend you to go the service center of the company. Please don't prefer local electronic shops as they might turn things worse.

I hope I was informative enough.

Comment: can u tell me best disk repair software to find out thay

Comment: Yes. There are several. You can try one or all of the following: Disk Drill, EaseUS Partition Master, WinDirStat, CloneZilla, Recuva, MiniTool Partition Wizard, etc

Comment: Once you succeed in recovering, please make sure that you run hard disk health checkup to ensure it won't corrupt again.

Comment: could it be any other problem, like strucking head at some place or platter problem or sata connector problem

Comment: I don't think so. But you may try replacing the cable. Sometimes by matter of luck, it may work. I my case nothing worked for me.

Comment: can u elaborate your problem

Comment: My problem was same as yours.

Comment: so whats the out come, it was repaired or what?

Comment: No... They were never in the position to repair

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for your problem is quite simple. The drive was working, it was dropped and is now not working. The simplest and most likely explanation is that the fall damaged the drive. The observed symptoms can be caused by logical damage but a fall will not cause such corruption without physical damage. Software will not repair physical damage.

Most likely the drives read write heads have been damaged. They are quite fragile can be seriously damaged by a fall much less than 1 meter. The heads are not user serviceable. This is normally done only by data recovery professionals. Special tools are needed and specific procedures followed. There are numerous precautions that are not at all obvious and many ways to go wrong. Multi platter drives, common with the higher capacities, are particularly difficult. Drives are only repaired for the purposes of data recovery, not for continued use of the drive.

In the event of drive damage it is important to make a decision early on if the data is worth the cost of professional recovery. If it is, do so. Many drives have been recovered to death. Repeated failed attempts will often damage the drive to such an extent that even professional recovery is no longer possible.

Files of any importance should have at least 1 backup copy, 2 or more copies if the files are of particular importance. Because of the handling they subjected to external drives tend to be less reliable than internal drives.

Comment: my toshoba device still have Warrenty, does they repair it or replace it if it has physical damage